# In a world where magic is the main spiritual path, how does this affect local goverment

Tags: magic

In this city not everyone fully practices magick but most people are aware that they can. Most people in power practice full magick openly as well as most of the citizens. 
What are some examples that this situation produces in the political relationships between people and politicians?

The rules that applies for the magick in this world are mostly this two:
- Psychick powers.
- Psychokinesis.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. This question has a couple problems with relation to the way this site works. First, it isn't really clear what you are talking about, especially when you say "the spiritual and existential path." Can you clarify what that means? The second problem is that this is too broad. You are asking us to describe all relationships in society from politics to the family. How could that be done with less than an encyclopedia? Please choose something much narrower to ask about. Thank you for coming here to Worldbuilding to contribute, I hope we can help you refine your question.

Comment: Please add what rules apply to your magic.

Comment: There is magick and then there is magick.  If magick entails the creation of armies from dragon teeth and restoring the dead to life, it would have different implications than if it entails making coins appear out of children's ears.

Comment: @Willk And then there's magick, entailing making coins appear out of dragon's ears... which arguably is still a pretty impressive feat =)

Comment: It will be helpful to read our [meta post about high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions).  It will help you understand how to narrow this question down.

Answer (score 1):

Theocracies would be favored as they would be the ones to be able to wield the most power. Religious education would be taught in schools, and so would using the spiritual practices to perform magick. Beyond that it would depend on whether one religion's spiritual practices can evoke more powerful or different magicks than the others, and how that works. The wars might become holy wars, and zealots would be very common and powerful.